# Why my imageJ has no menu?

Tags: imagej

[image]

I would like to use imageJ to read some video files, but I cannot see the menu in the interface, which means there is no "file", "edit"....options.
Could any one tell me why? thanks a lot!

OS: mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac the menu is always on the top left of the screen (not the window).

Comment: Thanks so much! That it is!